# Contact sharing belong to specific account

Tags: sharing, admin

Orgnization wants to share contact to be visible only to owners, with exception that contact belong to "XYZ.com" account should be visible to all the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Organization Wide Defaults to Private, then create a Criteria-Based Sharing Rule specifying the accounts you'd like to share.

Answer (score 0):

According to implicit sharing if Account is visible to All users then any child objects (records) will be visible to All users who have access to the account.

Refer [Implicit Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_implicit_sharing.htm) and [Built-in Sharing Behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_across_objects.htm&type=0)

> Access to child records—If you have access to a parent account, you have access to the associated child records. The account owner's role determines the level of access to child records.

So, basically, your use case cannot be supported by Salesforce.